# content activity main Conflict

Tags: android, android-layout

If I use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` when the app is running shows me the toolbar but I can't manipulate the fields in the content_main, but if I change to `setContentView(R.layout.content_main);` the fields works but the toolbar disappears.
What I can do to resolve this?

Main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int contador;
    boolean podeSwipe = true;

    ImageView photoImageViewBotton;
    ImageView photoImageViewTop;
    TextView nameTextbox;
    TextView descriptionTextbox;
    ConstraintLayout mainLayout;

    int[] listaImagens = {R.drawable.sheldon01, R.drawable.sheldon02, R.drawable.sheldon03, R.drawable.sheldon04, R.drawable.sheldon05};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Apontando o layout
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        (R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        photoImageViewTop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photoImageViewTop);
        photoImageViewBotton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photoImageViewBotton);
        nameTextbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTextbox);
        descriptionTextbox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextbox);
        mainLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        nameTextbox.setText("Sheldon,");
        descriptionTextbox.setTag(descriptionTextbox.getKeyListener());
        descriptionTextbox.setKeyListener(null);
        descriptionTextbox.setText("123456789" +
                "sdfsdfsdfs\n" +
                "sdfsdfsdfs\n" +
                "sdfsdfsdfs\n" +
                "sdfsdfsdfs\n" +
                "sdfsdfsdfs\n" +
                "sdfsdfsdfs\n" +"sdfsdfsdfs\n" +"sdfsdfsdfs\n" +"sdfsdfsdfs\n" +"sdfsdfsdfs\n" +"sdfsdfsdfs\n" +
                "dfsdfsdfsdfdsf\n" +"dfsdfsdfsdfdsf\n" +"dfsdfsdfsdfdsf\n" +"dfsdfsdfsdfdsf\n" +"dfsdfsdfsdfdsf\n" +"dfsdfsdfsdfdsf\n" +
                "dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf\n");

        photoImageViewBotton.setImageResource(R.drawable.sheldon02);
        photoImageViewTop.setImageResource(R.drawable.sheldon01);

        photoImageViewBotton.setAlpha(0.0f);
        photoImageViewBotton.setRotation(-30.0f);
        photoImageViewBotton.setScaleX(0.35f);
        photoImageViewBotton.setScaleY(0.35f);

        photoImageViewTop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                changePhoto();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Activity

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="zuch.co.a4aces.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/configurationButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:tint="@android:color/holo_purple"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/chatButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:tint="@color/Purple"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_action_chat" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/mainButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="zuch.co.a4aces.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/descriptionLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonRelactiveLayout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/photoImageViewTop"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/descriptionTextbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:elevation="1dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameTextbox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:editable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photoImageViewBotton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameTextbox"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sheldon03" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photoImageViewTop"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameTextbox"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sheldon03" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonRelactiveLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:tint="@android:color/background_light"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/heart" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/star01"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="163dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="457dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:tint="@android:color/background_light"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="2dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` 
and to access elements of `content_view` do

```
View contentView = findViewById(R.id.id_content_main);
```

and access the elements like

```
TextView tv=(TextView)contentView.findViewByID(R.id.some_id);
tv.setText("Anything");
```

Comment: Could you give some example of I can set the name in the textbox with that? I try to do it hera and shows only to edit the configurations of text, like set text aligment, gravity ... instead of set to a textbox

Comment: You added <include> twice ,remove the second one.

Comment: I was tryed it im my project and don't works, but I start a new and test in hello word, and works ... probably i will start a new project

Comment: Use `contentView.findViewById` for all views on `content_main.xml`